# Read file stream reader

Tags: c#, filestream

What is my mistake as I'm unable to find an example on the Internet that matches what I'm doing or at least I'm not sure if it does?

The problem I'm having is it does not like

```
hexIn = fileStream.Read()
```

Code:

```
FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(fileDirectory, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
String s;

try
{
    for (int i = 0; (hexIn = fileStream.Read() != -1; i++)
    {
        s = hexIn.ToString("X2");
        //The rest of the code
    }
}
finally
{
    fileStream.Close();
}
```

Comment: "It doesn't like it" is not a very detailed description. What is the exact problem you're having?

Answer (score 7):

Missing ")". . Try:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("TestFile.txt"))
{
    String line;

    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        s=...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things I would do differently.

The first, is you should using `FileStream` with a `using`. But actually, if you're just trying to read the lines in a text file, a `StreamReader` would be ok:

```
try
{
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("TestFile.txt"))
    {
        String line;

        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            // convert line to Hex and then format with .ToString("X2")
        }
    }
}
catch
{
    // handle error
}
```

If you're trying to convert your *entire* input file to a hex value, let us know. I'll just assume line-by-line for now.